# Caching is not working

Tags: c#, caching

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Caching;

 namespace Caching_IApiOutputCache_MemeoryCacheDefault
                                                                                                      {
    class Customer
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    }

class Cache
{
    MemoryCacheDefault mc = new MemoryCacheDefault();
    IEnumerable<Customer> cust = new List<Customer> { 
          new Customer { Name = "john", Id = 1 },
          new Customer { Name = "mark", Id = 2 } };
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCachedItems()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<Customer>)mc.Get("section");
    }

    public bool CacheIsEmptyOrFull()
    {
        //var mc = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (!mc.Contains("section"))
        {
            var expiration = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue;
            var Customers = cust;
            mc.Add("section", Customers, expiration);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Cache c = Cache.Instance;
        Cache c = new Cache();
        bool b = c.CacheIsEmptyOrFull();
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        IEnumerable<Customer> customer = c.GetCachedItems();
        foreach (var v in customer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Name + "'s" + " id is " + v.Id);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my code...It works fine no problem with it..But what confuses me is that when I run this code for the first time caching happens inside method CacheIsEmptyOrFull() and it returns false and then I get the collection from the cache itself and put it into a customer object in my Main() method. But when I run the code second time then why doesn't CacheIsEmptyOrFull() return a true, because cache already has a collection(given that I already ran the code and filled the cache) So CacheIsEmptyOrFull() must return a true and if statement inside this method shouldn't get executed second time (given the fact that cache has already something in it).
But this doesn't happen and every time I run the code it gives me false from CacheIsEmptyOrFull() method.

Why is this so? If Caching is happening then why the if statement gets executed every time I run the code.
Or my understanding of Caching is not proper, kindly help me on this one.

Comment: I've removed commented out pieces of your code - feel free to add them back. Also please add definition of `MemoryCacheDefault` type... And one more - there is exactly one call to `CacheIsEmptyOrFull` in your sample, but your post talks about calling that method second time - it would be useful to actually show two calls in a row (assuming you are not talking about running program twice)

Comment: yes I'm  talking about running the program twice. But...Whether I'm making 2 calls in a row or running program twice. Shouldn't caching behave the same way?

Comment: It is kind of hard for in-memory cache to survive process restrart... So clearly starting program twice will give you empty cache. I guess you expectations for caching based on behavior of external caching like memcached, but it is not how .Net in-memory cache behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Does your cache ever save to, and load from, any type of permanent storage?  If not, the cache will live in process memory only and will not persist after the process exists.  Basically, if you want to use data between program runs you need to persist to file, database, etc...

Comment: Got you, thats where I was kinda stuck, so its the process thats doing the trick and as soon as that process exits the in-memory caching is gone. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry I'm not on stackoverflow all that often, just saw you responded.  Yes as soon as the process exits the in-memory cache is gone.  If you want to persist a cache between process executions you'll need to write the data to a persistent storage.  Given your additional answer above, I'd actually recommend persisting the json data instead of a serialized generic collection.  It will probably be easier to read and maintain in case you need to check out the data you are caching and doesn't require you to serialize the objects back to string so theres a bit of perf savings.